# React Native multi line TextInput, text is centered

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, textinput

So when using, text input with multiline=true, I have this issue where the text is vertically centered instead of being pushed to the top.

This issue happens on both ios and android, except android has another issue where, when multiple lines are entered, they get letterboxed to the height of 1 line.

I'd like to point out, I have tried adding `textAlignVertical: 'top'` to the style of the textinput

Code: (I have this as a seperate copmonent as I use it in forms with form text but all parameters are passed something)

```
    <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={value}
            autoComplete={autoComplete}
            autoCapitalize={autoCapitalize}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
            keyboardType={keyboardType}
            returnKeyType={returnKeyType}
            autoFocus={autoFocus}
            onChangeText={onChangeText}
            onSubmitEditing={onSubmitEditing}
            multiline={multiline || false}
            ref={(r) => { inputRef && inputRef(r); }}
    />
```

styles:

```
input: {
    paddingRight: 10,
    lineHeight: 23,
    flex: 2,
    textAlignVertical: 'top'
},
```

**ios screenshot**
[image]

**android screenshot**
[image]

Comment: are you try to give height in style tag in textinput..?
or provide me the code you tried ....

Comment: Added code to question.

Comment: @chetangodiya do you have any ideas for a solution? No-one's solved it :(

Comment: i tried and add answer may be you should try and let me know if it is correct or not...

Comment: Looks like now on `iOS` it will be set on `top` automatically and for `Android` you can use `textAlignVertical: 'top'`

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#multiline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turned out the View surrounding the textinput had `alignItems: 'center'`
which centered the text within the text input.

So changed that to `alignItems: this.multiline ? 'flex-start' : 'center',`

Also for the android issue, I had to add `numberOfLines={5}` which fixed the letterboxing

Answer (score 86):

If anyone facing the same issue, try `textAlignVertical: "top"`
This works.
For more info try https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13897

Comment: It is for Android only. It's not working in iOS sadly.

Comment: If not working on iOS, try assigning a height style to the TextInput (as mentioned in the link of this answer, at the beginning)

Answer (score 21):

i tried this for you please let me know if its correct

```js
 <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChangeText={text=>this.setState({value:text})}
            multiline={true}
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
    />
```

style as

```js
  input: {
    width:200,
    borderBottomColor:'red',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
},
```

and **expo link** may be help you [**click here**](https://snack.expo.io/Hkts9SyGQ)

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `multiline` prop solved the problem.

```
   <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        value={this.state.value}
        onChangeText={text=>this.setState({value:text})}
        multiline={true}
        numberOfLines={4}
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case:

```
 textAlignVertical: multiline ? 'top' : 'center',
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this ok. Setting style `textAlignVertical: "top"` does not work. But setting as a **prop** of the multiline TextInput works. Use `textAlignVertical= "top"`