# How do I center align placeholder text while using multiline in React Native (IOS)

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

I am trying to vertically center my placeholder text within a  while also having the multiline attribute. I seems that for IOS it automatically pushes my placeholder a d text to the top. How can I center it again?

I’ve tried justifying content, aligning and everything else.

Comment: Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native multi line TextInput, text is centered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985180/react-native-multi-line-textinput-text-is-centered)